# How to stop a running pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to rerun from a faild activity and getting the follwong error
Where and how can I cancel this recovery run ?

```
{"code":"RerunConcurrentGroupInProgress","message":"Cannot rerun this pipeline. There's another recovery run in progress for group id e6d87323-fb60-4951-a04a-95d26855d65c","target":null,"details":null}
```

any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Go to the Monitor tab in your ADF or Synapse workspace.
Look for recent pipeline runs, especially those with the status indicating they are in progress or have failed. You can use the provided group ID (e6d87323-fb60-4951-a04a-95d26855d65c in your case) to help locate the specific run.
Check the details of the in-progress or failed runs to identify which one corresponds to the recovery run mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Once you've identified the in-progress recovery run, you can cancel it directly from the UI:

In the Monitor tab, find the run you identified as the recovery run.
Select the run to view its details.
Look for an option to cancel the run. This option might be represented by a Cancel button or a similar UI element.
Confirm the cancellation of the run. This action should stop the recovery run and free up your pipeline to be rerun.

Comment: Great. Posting the same as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue and proceed with your desired rerun, you'll need to either wait for the current recovery run to complete or manually cancel the in-progress recovery run. Here's how you can approach this:

First, you need to identify the recovery run that's currently in progress. This can typically be done within the Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics UI:
[image: Screenshot of list view for monitoring pipeline runs.]

- Go to the **Monitor** tab in your ADF or Synapse workspace.
- Look for recent pipeline runs, especially those with the status indicating they are in progress or have failed. You can use the provided group ID (`e6d87323-fb60-4951-a04a-95d26855d65c` in your case) to help locate the specific run.
- Check the details of the in-progress or failed runs to identify which one corresponds to the recovery run mentioned in the error message.

Once you've identified the in-progress recovery run, you can cancel it directly from the UI:

- In the **Monitor** tab, find the run you identified as the recovery run.
- Select the run to view its details.
- Look for an option to cancel the run. This option might be represented by a **Cancel** button or a similar UI element.
- Confirm the cancellation of the run. This action should stop the recovery run and free up your pipeline to be rerun.

Reference:
[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-visually)